# node.js webserver and C++ game server

Tags: c++, c, node.js, sockets, websocket

This question may be too broad, but I think it's a decent question to ask, and I'm not sure how to handle it.

I'm currently hosting a website at example.com. I'm doing this using 100% node.js, at the moment. I'm also hosting a networked HTML5 game (at game.example.com) that uses `socket.io`, which is fantastic, but I have decided that I would rather handle the game server using C++ (or, potentially, Java) and am planning on translating the server logic from JavaScript.

My biggest problem at the moment is that I simply don't know how I would connect the WebSocket. I still plan on serving the full client (HTML and JavaScript) using node.js, but I would like the client to connect to the C++ server rather than the node.js server.

The way that I'm currently connecting to the server is simply using a socket gained from socket.io's `io.connect();`. I think this can remain, I just need to pass the socket on the server-side from node.js to my C++ program, and I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This might be old but could you please briefly mention the reason you want to migrate from nodejs to c++? was it slow?

Comment: Haha, this is old, isn't it? I don't remember the exact reasons, but it was a pet project, so I probably just wanted to practice C++ at the time.

Comment: Okies, thnx for your answer I was thinking about writing a game server in nodejs and came up to this post, so I thought to ask you :)

Comment: The biggest reason I'd say not to write a game server in node is that it's not multi-threaded. It's going to depend on the game, but most game servers rely on one or more threads to run the game loop and spin off multiple threads to communicate to the clients. But you can totally do it using Node and `setInterval`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, you want Node to handle regular HTTP requests, but you want to pass Websocket requests to your C++ server? Try using a proxy in Node for the upgrade requests:

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

//have your c++ server for websockets operating on port 1333
var proxy = new httpProxy.HttpProxy({
  target: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 1333
  }
});

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //handle normal requests in here
});

server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  // Proxy websocket requests...
  proxy.proxyWebSocketRequest(req, socket, head);
});

server.listen(80);
```

Answer (score 3):

First, there's the option of connecting your clients directly to your C++ server. If your socket.io transport is websockets, for example, you can use http://libwebsockets.org (a C++ websockets library for the server-side).

Otherwise, you could let your clients connect the socket.io to your node.js server, and establish some simple communication between your C++ server and node.js server. Don't try to "handle off the socket.io to the C++ server": simply have the C++ server and the node.js server communicate between themselves, passing messages back and forth, about players' states: the C++ would handle the logic, and the node.js would do the actual sending and receiving. You can do that, for example, with a simple TCP socket.